# How do I enable tabs in tabview in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I have a TabView that contains two tabs. the first tab has Boutton. How do I enable the second tab on click of a command button

```
  <p:tabView id="tabView"  widgetVar="tabPanelWidget1">

        <p:tab id="firstTab" title="tab1">
            <h:form id="form1">
                      .........................
            <p:commandButton action="#{Bean.create}" value="Add" 
                         update=":content:tabView" />

            </h:form>
        </p:tab>

       <p:tab id="secondtab"  title="tab 2">
             <h:form id="form2">
                               .............
              </h:form>
       </p:tab>
 </p:tabView>
```

Comment: Does it have to be with ajax? You will get better results with the primefaces tab javascript API

Comment: Show me your method if you can please!

Answer (score 0):

Use primefaces' tab javascript api, specifically the `select` function thus:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{Bean.create}" onclick="tabView.select(1);" value="Add" update=":content:tabView"/>
```

The *1* argument to the function is the index of the tab that you wish to switch to.